# How to replace fragment inside another fragment in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

So, I use the latest version of androidstudio and kotlin.

I created a bottom navigation activity project, and I use the activity with the drefault generated code.

I would like to open/replace a fragment from another fragment by button. 
But the previous fragment doesn't disappear, when the new fragment is appear, so both are visible.

I read a lot, but I don't know the solution, please help me with some advice.

This is my MainActivity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle ? ) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
        R.id.navigation_advertisements, R.id.navigation_own_advertisements, R.id.navigation_chat, R.id.navigation_party, R.id.navigation_settings))
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}
```

And this is my fragment

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle ? ) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    button.setOnClickListener {
        activity!!.supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, ChatFragment())
            .commit()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using the `Navigation Architecture Component` then you don't have to do what you are doing in the `setOnClickListener` method. You should be using the `findNavController().navigate(id, bundle, null, null)`. Here id is the id of your fragment.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it didn't help, bacause this fragment what i want to show, not part of the menu, I tried to register the fragment in mobile.navigation.xml but when I tried to open, i got an exception (does not have a NavController set on 2131230914)

Comment: Watch some tutorials about how to properly use `Navigation Architecture Component` I think you got it wrong.